# Javascript to check if a number value is zero (and not null) or above but not negative

Tags: javascript, vue.js, numbers

I'm trying to determine if a value entered into a HTML input (type="number") is zero or above, but not negative. I'm doing this using Vue, and have the following Sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/2zxkm6j0vp?fontsize=14

The offending code is in 'App.vue' file.

I have a `data` property called `inputNumber` and this is initially set to `null`. There's an input field where the user can enter a value (which is in turn bound (using `v-model` with `trim` and `number` modifiers)) to the input.

I then have a `computed` property that returns the result of a check (`return Number(this.inputNumber) >= 0`. This works fine when the value of `inputNumber` is either less than `0` (there's an error shown) or greater than `0` (there's a positive result shown). If `0` is entered it should return a positive message, as that should be an 'amount' that the user can enter. Currently no message is shown when `0` is entered.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: If zero (`0`) is entered it should return a positive message, as that should be an 'amount' that the user can enter. Currently no message is shown when zero is entered.

Comment: Oh I see. pfx answer is good.

Comment: I don't know much about VUE but based on your code, it looks like view is ignoring 0 as a value altogether so that your compute function gets null as the value for `this.inputNumber`

Comment: don't paste code off-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inputNumber will be false if it equals 0 here:

```
<p v-if="inputNumber && isValid">{{ inputNumber }} is valid</p>
```

That's why it doesn't show.

To fix that we can replace that line with

```
<p v-if="inputNumber !== '' && isValid">{{ inputNumber }} is valid</p>
```

and initialize inputNumber with ''

```
data() {
  return {
    inputNumber: ''
  }
},
```

If we leave it as null, once you input a value and the empty the input field, inputNumber won't be null anymore and "is valid" will keep showing up.

Comment: Yup, that's worked, thanks. Changing the return statement of `isValid` to `return this.inputNumber !== '' && Number(this.inputNumber) >= 0` has worked too. Then I can leave `<p v-if="isValid">{{ inputNumber }} is valid</p>` - which is a little cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
<p v-if="inputNumber && isValid">{{ inputNumber }} is valid</p>
```

by

```
<p v-if="isValid">{{ inputNumber }} is valid</p>
```

The `if inputNumber` check will return `false` when being `0`.

---

**EDIT**

Extend the `isValid` check as below, taking into account the `null`value and also an empty value (when the textfield gets cleared).

```
computed: {
    isValid() {      
        return (this.inputNumber !== null)  && (this.inputNumber !== '') && (+this.inputNumber >= 0);      
}

<p v-if="isValid">{{ inputNumber }} is valid</p>
<p v-else-if="!isValid">{{ inputNumber }} is not valid</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a little closer, but if the value of `inputNumber` is as it's initially set, `null` then the check returns `true`.